# How too not clear a input when clearing the console?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, function, while-loop

When I clear the console to refresh something with

```py
from replit import clear
def cls():
  clear()
```

This clears the screen on a thread every 3 or so seconds but when doing that i have a input on the main thread for message inputs

```py
def main(nick):


  while True:
    message = input("")
    if message == "!exit":
      break
    else:
      data = {
        "message":message,
        "author":nick
      }
      requests.post(f"{glob.serverUrl}/postMessage", json=data)
```

I have tried to find a fix but have not been able to find anything

Comment: What does sys.stdin.buffer.read().decode() give you if it were inserted into top line of cls()?  [incidentally, is using cls wise as its a predefined class method?] I'm thinking you may be able to parse the current screen, clear it, then recreate it as necessary for user to input (you'd need to hand back any partial string from cls() though)

Comment: it stops refreshing

Comment: And it doesn't give you the current text on screen?

If it were me, I'd make a quick small pyQt gui for this, as you could run it in a separate thread that definitely won't have its data cleared. I know it'd work as I've done similar, and it'd by my quickest way to a solution.

But, I assume an approach like that is out of the question here?